# Laravel migrations don't set default FALSE in PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I can't set a default value `false` for boolean column in PostgreSQL database while using Laravel migrations.

PostgreSQL version is 11, Laravel version 10.

I have tried the following variations of migration:

```
Schema::create('raw_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->boolean('columnName')->default(new Expression('false'));
    ...
});
```

```
Schema::create('raw_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->boolean('columnName')->default(false);
    ...
});
```

```
Schema::create('raw_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->boolean('columnName')->default(0);
    ...
});
```

as well as adding the following statement in the current migration or different migration altogether:
`DB::statement("ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnName SET DEFAULT false;");`

Neither of these works, the table gets created, but the column never has the default value:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName
(
    ...
    columnName boolean NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

Interestingly, `true` is also never set as default value.

However, when I run the `ALTER` statement in PgAdmin, the default value `false` is set correctly:
`ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnName SET DEFAULT false;`

Is there a way to do this with Laravel migrations?

Comment: This seems unlikely. Are you undoing the migration before re-running it? Migrations will only run once, even if you change their code. Does a fresh from-scratch database (i.e. `php artisan migrate:fresh`; careful, because this wipes everything) exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, `php artisan migrate:fresh` is the command that I use for testing in this case. Other changes in migration files appear in the database, but not default values for boolean columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - the issue was that in a later migration I was adding comments to existing columns, including `columnName`. As I wasn't adding `->default(false)` to the later migration, this default value was dropped, as per Laravel documentation- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#modifying-columns.
In similar situations you have to include all column modifiers that you wish to keep.